# my page height causes issues with gridview

Tags: asp.net, css

when my gridview gets bigger with the data i.e when the page size increases to 10, the gridview gets outside the main page area. The image describes clearly my words. can anybody please help me to solve the issue? Thanks.[image]

```
    my CSS:

        body
        {
            margin-top: 0px;
            background-image: url('../Images/bg_gradient.png');
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            background-color: #c6dee8;
        }

        #wrapper
        {
            border: 0px solid green;
            width: 980px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }


            #main
        {
            width: 978px;
            min-height: 750px;
            max-height: 1000px;
            overflow: auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #leftContent
        {
            width: 180px;
            min-height: 750px;
            max-height: 1000px;
            float: left;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
        }
#recordDisplaydiv
{
    padding-top: 50px;
}

My Markup Code:

        <div id="recordDisplaydiv">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvContract" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ContractID"
                            CssClass="mGrid" OnPageIndexChanging="gvContract_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="gvContract_RowCommand"
                            EmptyDataText="No Record Exist" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="KeyWinCountNumber" HeaderText="KeyWin Count#" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemName" HeaderText="Item" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="BrandName" HeaderText="Brand" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CountName" HeaderText="Count" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SellerName" HeaderText="Seller" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="BuyerName" HeaderText="Buyer" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractNumber" HeaderText="Contract#" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractDate" HeaderText="Contract Date" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryFromName" HeaderText="Country From" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryToName" HeaderText="Country To" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitName" HeaderText="Unit Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TQty" HeaderText="Total Qty" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Vans" HeaderText="Vans" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Unit Price" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TAmount" HeaderText="Total Amount" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# isDelete_img(Session["isAdmin"].ToString()) %>'
                                            CommandName="DeleteRecord" Enabled='<%# isDelete(Session["isAdmin"].ToString()) %>'
                                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ContractID") %>' AlternateText="DeleteRecord" OnClientClick="return confirm_delete();"
                                            Style='<%# delete_style(Session["isAdmin"].ToString()) %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" CommandName="EditRecord"
                                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ContractID") %>' AlternateText="EditRecord" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <div id="ContractbtnExportdiv">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" CssClass="btnExportdiv" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting the main container to have a scrollbar to show the overflow or are you wanting the container to expand with the gridview?

Comment: Are we able to see your front-end code? From the looks of things you've got a fixed height on your container which is causing the gridview to overflow rather than force the container to expand. You can set overflow: auto; on the container but that'll give a scrollbar. If I can see your code I can give more help

Comment: yea sure, @alimac83 .. i`m posting it. wait.

Comment: wait, @alimac83.. sorry i didnt see this comment of yours.

Answer (score 1):

put gridview in scrollable div that will resolve issue

```
<div style="width:300px;height:250px;overflow:auto;">
  <gridview>
</div>
```

Comment: when i added an overflow into the #main{} it worked, but a scroll bar appeared. and secondly, the #leftContent border disappears from the bottom when i scroll down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-y:auto;` property to fix the issue.

```
div.classname {
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: i did this as told by other commenter but when the scroll bar appears and when i scroll down, the leftContent border disappers from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

```
max-height: 1000px;
```

from your #main and #leftContent divs

Answer (score -1):

Use overflow-y as auto and remove `maximum-height` for both panels i.e. for `#main` and `#leftContent` and apply height as 100% as auto to `#leftContent`. This might help.

Comment: no, this also aint solving the issue, i actuallly dont want a scroll bar, but i want my page to dynamically increase its height according to the data placed in the gridview.

Comment: then try increasing the max height value. instead of setting it to 1000px set it to large value. ex. 1800px